# Why does jQuery work the same for most browsers?

Tags: jquery, cross-browser

I've read that one of the advantages of jQuery is that it works most of the time in most popular browsers. I'm just wondering, why is that?

Comment: Because that's the main point of jQuery.  Uniformity of code cross-browser.  Lots of conditionals looking at specific scenarios to fix any inconsistencies.  [You can see the code for yourself](http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js).

Comment: This behavior is by design.

Comment: why would you expect it not to?

Comment: Thanks, Sparky. jQuery is magical. :)

Answer (score 5):

Because jQuery is full of special-case code to work around inconsistencies in different browsers.